# How to have a desktop shortcut trigger a code event?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, desktop

I've been trying to make an application in C# that has different events trigger when a shortcut on the desktop is opened, and I am not sure how to do this. The only things I could think of was opening the program with additional arguments, but I want the program to already be open when the shortcut does something.

Any information would be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean any shortcut or still a shortcut to your own application? You could derive from [`WindowsFormsApplicationBase`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.applicationservices.windowsformsapplicationbase(v=vs.110).aspx) to create a singleton application (that runs only once per machine) and can notify the already running instance when started again.

Comment: This question is a bit too broad, however you could start the app again with args, and do an initial check for a running preexisting app and send a windows message or similar IPC technique to the preexisting app , then close

Comment: You can hook into windows process creation via WMI, and inspect the process that was launched, and respond accordingly. Or, you could be more brute force and just poll the process list in a loop, watching for changes. Finally, there are windows hooks for shell actions, this would require some COM interop, but you should be able to register a windows hook for shell launch actions in your application and respond.

Comment: You might want to use a single instance method that accepts arguments and gives them to the first instance. There are multiple guides available for this using Mutex (for instance detection) and Named Pipes (for argument passing).